# Xamarin.Forms App crashes when clicking on Entry, returns "NullReferenceException"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

(Problem is solved, creating this since the solution is not online)

When clicking on Entry, the keyboard pops up on the Android emulator and then the app crashes with a NullReferenceException, object not found.

Initially I thought it was a problem in my ViewModel due to the Entry having a Binding to an object in the ViewModel.

I then came to the conclusion that you cannot Bind Entries to ViewModels to both display and update properties of an object, since I couldn't find any clear cut examples of this online. You have to use a button/event that applies the properties to Entry.text or updates the object property with Entry.text.

I fixed this so my Entry had no bindings and the problem still occurred even using a fresh Entry on a fresh page. I lost the stacktrace but it began by saying something along the lines of "xamarin.forms.grid.NumberOfUnsetRows..."

I then remembered that I had attempted to create a custom Entry renderer awhile ago, but deleted the files. This messed up the code behind that created Entries.

Solution: Reinstall Xamarin.Forms Nuget Package. This undid the damage from the custom Entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall Xamarin.Forms Nuget Package. This undid the damage from the custom Entry